# CSE does not pick up url from href attribute in a Element when using Microdata

Tags: javascript, schema.org, microdata

I am trying to extract the book URL from a link using microdata. The format is specified in schema.org. Here is my html.

```
  <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-3" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Book">
                    <div class="thumbnail">
                        <img src="{{ book.thumbnailurl }}" itemprop="thumbnailUrl" style="width: 100px;height: 200px;">
                        <div class="caption">
                            <h4><span itemprop="name">{{ book.name }}</span> - <span itemprop="author">{{ book.author }}</span></h4>
                            <p><span itemprop="about"> {{ book.about }}</span></p>
                            <p> 

                                    <a href="{{ book.url }}" itemprop="url" onclick="trackOutboundLink(‘{{ book.name }}’);">
                                      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-md">
                                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-book"></span>Read
                                      </button>
                                    </a>

                            </p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                 </div>
```

When I use google [snippet testing tool](http://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/richsnippets?q=http://cfc-melbourne-website.appspot.com/home/books) the JSON API returns book as a html link. However when I make the call in javascript the value of url is text("Read").

The javascript - [full file](http://cfc-melbourne-website.appspot.com/static/js/custom.js)

```
function PrintSearchResults(result) {
    var $result = $("<a href='" + result["link"] + "' class='list-group-item'></a>");
    var $title = $("<h4 class='list-group-item-heading'>" + result['title'] + "</h4>");
    var $snippet = $("<p class='list-group-item-text'>" + result['htmlSnippet'] + "</p>");
    $result.append($title);
    // handle the pagemap if its available. 
    if(result["pagemap"] != undefined){
        var pagemap = result["pagemap"];
        if(pagemap["thumbnail"] != undefined){
            var src = pagemap["thumbnail"][0]["src"];
            var width = 50;
            var height = 50;
            var $thumbnail = $("<div id='result-container'><div class='pull-left' style='margin-right:6px;'><img src='" + src + "' style='width:" + width + "px; height: " + height + "px;'/></div></div>");
            $result.height("100%");
            $result.append($thumbnail); 
        }
    }
    $result.append($snippet);
    if(result["pagemap"] != undefined){
        var pagemap = result["pagemap"];
        if(pagemap["book"]!= undefined){
            $result.append("<hr/>")
            $result.append("<div><em>Other books you may be interested in.</em></div>")
            $booklist = $("<ul style='list-style-type: none;'></ul>");
            pagemap["book"].forEach(function(b){
                var thumbnailurl = b["thumbnailurl"];
                var name = b["name"];
                var author = b["author"];
                var about = b["about"];
                var url = b["url"];
                $booklist.append("<li><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-book' style='margin-right:10px;'></span>" + name + "</li>");
            });

            var $listdivs = $("<div style='margin-left:15px;'></div>");
            $listdivs.append($booklist);
            $result.append($listdivs);
        }
    }
    $('.list-group').append($result);
    HideDisplay();
}
```

This is my query to site search - [query](https://www.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1?key=AIzaSyCMGfdDaSfjqv5zYoS0mTJnOT3e9MURWkU&cx=007141654281892448754:2g0faqsp4_q&q=a%20good%20foundation)

What am i missing ?

Comment: "However when I make the call in javascript the value of url is text("Read")."  Perhaps it would help if you showed that code?

Comment: @Joshua Taylor -Updated the question with the javascript.

Comment: Have you done anything else with code?  Can you retrieve anything else?  Do you get the correct value for other things?  A little bit of debugging can go a long way…  When you say "when I make the call in javascript" do you mean that you're calling the Google snippet tool from javascript?  Where are you doing that?

Comment: I have also included the query I am sending to site search. The JSON that is returned contains, all the information, except the URL of the book.

Comment: I'm no javascript guru, but I don't see where you're calling the webservice.  I just see code that's generating some HTML, if I'm not mistaken.  Am I wrong?

Comment: Just included the entire js file, custom.js

Comment: With your snippet testing tool, do note that it does say "url: Read", although "Read" is a hyperlink there.  "Read" is also the text that's within (the button within) your anchor element.  Something getting confused, perhaps?

Comment: So I guess without change the word Read to the value of the hyper link, is there another way to get the value of the hyperlink.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/55539/discussion-between-joesoc-and-joshua-taylor).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok finally after a lot of digging, I have the answer.

The root cause is as follows: 
The Google CSE(Custom Search Engine) is not consuming the microdata property value as the href attribute of the "a" HTML element. It is consuming the child text content on the "a" HTML element.

The Google CSE is able to consume the href from a "link" HTML element.

Therefore.

```
 <a href="{{ book.url }}" itemprop="url" onclick="trackOutboundLink(‘{{ book.name }}’);">
```

will not work.

```
 <link itemprop="url" href="{{ book.url }}">
 <a href="{{ book.url }}" onclick="trackOutboundLink(‘{{ book.name }}’);">
```

works.